# Id.ValueOf complains, even though it's a valid ID..?

Tags: salesforce, apex

TL;DR - the below problem seems to affect Developer Console, but not running from VSCode...

I've uploaded a static resource which is a CSV containing a bunch of IDs.

I now want to build up a list of these ID's to pass into a class for processing, so I'm doing the following, in Developer Console:

```
StaticResource sr = [SELECT body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'MY_RESOURCE' LIMIT 1];

String body = sr.Body.toString();
String[] filelines = body.split('\r\n');

List<Id>opps = new List<Id>();

for (Integer i=0;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    Id oppId = Id.valueOf(filelines[i].trim());

    opps.add(oppId);
}
```

However, where I try and construct the ID (inside the for loop) it complains with an error like this:

`System.StringException: Invalid id: ﻿0066700000wirvdAAA`

That's obviously a valid ID (and if I manually execute `Id someId = Id.ValueOf('0066700000wirvdAAA');` it's fine.

The running theory is some weird invisible control characters (we had to put the `trim()` in when running this from VSCode to get it to execute without the same error). I tried a slightly bonkers approach of stripping everything off and trying to force it to be a plain string :D

```
String currentId = String.valueOf(filelines[i]).replace('\r', '').replace('\n','').replace('"','').trim() ;
    System.debug(currentId);
    
    Id oppId = Id.valueOf(currentId);
```

But this still fails.

Comment: My colleague has discovered this is probably a leading zero-width space causing trouble, probably due to the CSV making up the static resource. Will answer if I find the proper fix!

Answer (score 0):

So as suspected, this was an encoding issue caused by saving the CSV as the default UTF-8 encoding. Picking the plain CSV option in the Save-As dialog solves the problem.
It seems the Apex `trim()` doesn't remove the zero length spaces...